# Why Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt occurs in this situtation?

Tags: flutter

In the code bloew you can find where the problem exactly happens, but I don't actually know why it happens because I'm using the same method in code in another widget and it worked perfectly.

It occurs because of this line of code `Text("${(progress * 100).toInt()} %"),`

Here in this widget the code works perfectly:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smart_tank1/main_tank_ui/home/main_tank_home_page.dart';

class MainTankCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentWater;
  final int remainingWater;
  final double progress;
  MainTankCardWidget({
    @required this.currentWater,
    @required this.remainingWater,
    @required this.progress,
  }
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(MainTankHomePage.routeName);
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 240,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            child: Card(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              elevation: 5,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Main Tank'),
                                        Container(
                                              height: 40,
                                              width: 100,
                                              child: Card(
                                              //  color: Colors.blue,
                                                color: progress >=  0.70 ? Colors.greenAccent : 
                                                progress >= 0.50 ? Colors.yellow : 
                                                Colors.red ,
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                                ),
                                                child: Center(
                                                 // child: Text('Normal', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),),
                                                  child: progress >= 0.70 ? 
                                                  Text('Good', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),) : progress >= 0.50 ?
                                                  Text('Normal', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),) : 
                                                  Text('Low', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),)  
                                                  ),
                                                  ),
                                            ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 30,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text('$currentWater'),
                                          Text('$remainingWater'),
                                          Text("${(progress * 100).toInt()} %"),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text('Liters'),
                                          Text('Remaining'),
                                          Text('Rate'),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ), 
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    );
        }
      }
```

Here is where it doesn't work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SumpTankCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentWater;
  final int remainingWater;
  final double progress;

  SumpTankCardWidget({
    @required this.currentWater,
    @required this.remainingWater,
    @required this.progress,
  }
  );
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
                        height: 240,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                //---------
                                //Card2
                                //---------
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text('Sump Tank'),
                                      Container(
                                            height: 40,
                                            width: 100,
                                            child: Card(
                                              color: progress >=  0.70 ? Colors.greenAccent : 
                                              progress >= 0.50 ? Colors.yellow : 
                                              Colors.red ,
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                              ),
                                              child: Center(
                                                child: progress >= 0.70 ? 
                                                Text('Good', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),) : progress >= 0.50 ?
                                                Text('Normal', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),) : 
                                                Text('Low', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),)  
                                                ),
                                                ),
                                          )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('$currentWater'),
                                        Text('$remainingWater'),
                                        Text("${(progress * 100).toInt()} %"),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('Liters'),
                                          Text('Remaining'),
                                          Text('Rate'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),                              
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    );
        }
        
      }
```

Comment: I just solved it,  the problem was happening because the int number in database was 0 and it should not be 0 in the UI